# Microsoft Expression Encoder not working on Surface Pro

Tags: c#, wpf, surface, expression-encoder

I have a c# wpf project which contains dlls from Microsoft Expression Encoder for webcam recording. I have installed this project on many machines and can record from the webcam fine. But someone at my work place tried it on a surface pro and it doesnt work.

Is there any reason as to why it shouldnt work on a Surface Pro?

Answer (score 0):

Have them try using a mouse.

I'm currently trying to use Expression Encoder to do a screen capture, and noticed that it doesn't seem to update when I use my touch screen, but is fine if I use a mouse.

Edit: Changing "Capture mouse cursor" in the settings to "no" fixes it so that touch capture will work